# Why does the XMLHTTP Request doesn't work with my server?

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax

I've rented a server and have a website right now. But I have a problem: I want to refer Textfiles I've saved on the server and load the content into a String. I've tried the following:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var filePath = "the link";
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET",filePath,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
var fileContent = xmlhttp.responseText;
var fileArray = fileContent.split('\n')
//Now do whatever you need with the array
window.alert(fileArray);
</script>
```

The problem ist: I doesn't work :-( I can load other Textfiles (e. g. from GitHub) but referencing Textfiles on my server constantly fails to work! The files are publically available and can be read and executed. I also tried to get the content via Java:

```js
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("the link");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }

}
```

This code works fine (even for my server files). Can you help me? Why isn't it working?

Comment: Highly doubt this has anything to do with Ajax. So if you call your url directly in the browser, does it have the same issue?

Comment: probably `cors` issue? any errors in console?

Comment: Apart CORS issue, synchronous XHR have been deprecated (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open). Maybe your browser is blocking the requests ?

Comment: @epascarello No, I don't have the same problem calling the file in the browser via URL.

Comment: Okay start to debug it on the client, any errors in the console? What is the statusText? What is in the response? console.log() is your friend. Is the alert() being blocked?

Comment: What is "the link" value, not the real one but what is is, an external IP, a domain name, ... a local adress ?

Comment: @AxelH "The link" is a simple URL like "https: //mydomain.com/xyz.txt".

Comment: See what is [CORS - Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely a `cors` issue as @Alex already assumed. You can fix this by adding the option `Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"` to your `.htaccess` on the server.